# Why can't I access the HTML of some websites

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've been trying to learn how to extract data from websites efficiently using python. Ideally I'd like to gather from stats in a more efficient manner than I currently am doing on the site www.transfermarkt.com, a footballing website but for some reason the site seems to behave different from every other site I've tried. Even the simple code below just gives me basically no response. Can anybody explain why I cant get the HTML of this website but I can with other websites.

```
import urllib
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.transfermarkt.com")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
print (htmltext)
```

Comment: Haven't looked at it, but the site may be rendered with JavaScript (while all the server outputs would be JSON data to be interpreted by the client, for instance). In such a case, to access HTML you'll need a JavaScript-capable client such as PhantomJS or Selenium.

Comment: Some website incorporate an anti-scraping protectuon to prevent this kind of data retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `urllib#urlopen` documentation:

> One caveat: the read() method, if the size argument is omitted or
>   negative, may not read until the end of the data stream; there is no
>   good way to determine that the entire stream from a socket has been
>   read in the general case.

If you check the response headers for the site you're trying to read, you'll see that there's no `Content-Length` header, this is because the transfer is chunked and you need to read all those chunks before getting the content.

```
data = htmlfile.read(512)
while data is not None:
    htmltext += data
```

And the thing that Aswin pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

The site you specified had blocked robots in http://www.transfermarkt.com/robots.txt .So you have to access with user agent as a browser.

So basically you code should be

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open("http://www.transfermarkt.com")
print (response.read())
```